# Pass multiple array indexes to jquery trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to pass multiple array indexes to a jquery trigger event.

At the moment I have an array and I pass the following to pull just the first item:

```
$("#my-nav a").eq(1).trigger("click");
```

Is it possible to pull more than one .eq(1) ?

Cheers

Comment: Btw `eq(1)` is the second link

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Get some links and then arbitrarly trigger click on some of them? e.g. on [1,5,14]? Or you just want to trigger 'click' on all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
$("#my-nav a").filter(function(i){
    return $.inArray(i, [1,3,5]) > -1;
})
```

Where the array in `inArray` are the needed index.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2LpXM/1/

If you want to pass array to `.eq()`, you cant insert this in your code :

```
$.fn._eq = $.fn.eq;

$.fn.eq = function(arg){
    if($.isArray(arg))
        return this.filter(function(i){
            return $.inArray(i, arg) > -1;
        });
    else
        return this._eq(arg);
}
```

then use `$el.eq(arr);`

Comment: Thats pretty cool.  What if it was a JSON object and i represented the key for other objects?

Comment: {"nike":[{"logo":"images\/nike.png","description":"some nike text"},{"logo":"images\/nike.png","description":"some nike text"},{"logo":"images\/nike.png","description":"some nike text"}]  So What if I had a big bunch of these in addition to Nike ie Puma, Addidas, Hi-Tec, Gola.  I would like to be able to display every brand as key

Comment: @Volterony i dont see how this is related with `.eq()`. Would you please explain a little bit more what you want to achieve?

Comment: Here is a fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/volterony/9kSep/  At the moment, $("#brand-nav a").eq(0).trigger("click"); just loads the first object's items, but I want to display multiple object items

Comment: @Volterony after getting your fiddle to work (http://jsfiddle.net/9kSep/1/), it seem that i can't find any `.trigger()`. Also, when you click on a click, you erase the current content. That mean event if you trigger multiple `a`, only the last `a` will be shown.

Comment: Karl I really appreciate your help.  Sorry for the confusion.  I am just looking for a way to display multiple brand items on page load. From your fiddle you can see that I can successfully load 1 item, but I would like to load all items from every brand.  I thought .trigger() would be the answer but not sure how to do it?

Comment: @Volterony my answer will be disappointing for you... Your problem inst with trigger, but it is the fact that you use `innerHTML` which override you HTML. The solution would be to check, when click on the link, if there is a `div` with a given id for each brand. If there is one, you remove it, else you had one without `innerHTML`. That is the only thing i can say. I would be happy to help with further problems, but right now, i don't have the time to develop that. Sorry, I hope it help you..

Comment: Not a problem Karl, you have been extremely helpful and I will move forward with your ideas.  Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [:lt()](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) or [:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

```
$("#my-nav a:lt(5)")
```

---

`.eq()` is zero indexed based

so first element is `.eq(0)`

---

```
$("#my-nav a").slice(index)
```

Comment: This only seems to pull the items for array key 5?  Is it possible to pull multiple array keys?  gt() seems to get the last item

Comment: Try `$("#my-nav a").filter(':lt(5)')`

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what elements you're after. You can use the :lt() and :gt() as Tushar advised or you can use the [:nth-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector which is pretty powerful:

```
$( '#my-nav a:nth-child( -n+4 )' ).trigger( 'click' ); // Only the first four elements
$( '#my-nav a:nth-child( even )' ).trigger( 'click' ); // Any even elements.
```

CSS Tricks has some [useful nth-child examples](http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/).